# Delete specific rows from the database

Tags: mysql

How can I delete all rows from my database which have got Kills=0?

[screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBHp.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Google *SQL tutorial*.  Databases don't have lines. Paper has lines. Text files have lines. Concerts and department stores have lines. Database tables have rows.

Comment: To [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM <table name> WHERE (Kills=0);
```

But in all seriousness, go read some MySQL documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer!